# Manage Huge PHP Class File

Tags: php, maintainability

I have a huge php class with very long code in it. This make the file is big with lots of coding and hard to maintain. Is there anyway that I can split the class into a few files for easier maintaining?

Thank you.

Comment: Sure, there is some way: refactoring.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If your class is too huge, maybe you should rethink your app architecture.

Comment: thats why they provided class hierarchy, a good thing to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you can split the class in to subclasses.

What I mean is that you should ask yourself "does this method apply to this class or would it belong to a subclass?"

For example,

```
Class Animal
  - dog_bark()
```

`dog_bark()` could be moved to a class named Dog, and the method renamed to bark()